# TFS - Getting Work items from the Build Work Item

Tags: c#

So I'm researching how I could possibly create a utility where I enter in the Build Work Item and it returns all the Work Items associated to it.

We already have code that will get the files associated to the individual work items.

Is this possible?  If so, I'm looking for research suggestions.  I'm not at the coding state yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean by Build WorkItem

Here's a blog article on [Querying on WorkItem Links through the API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgorti/archive/2007/09/26/querying-on-workitem-links-through-the-api.aspx)

Esstentially a workitem has a property `WorkItemLinks` which lets you get the link type (`LinkType.BaseReferenceName`), link name (`LinkType.Name`) and workitem id (`TargetId`).  You can then load up the related workitems like you'd load any workitem (`WIStore.GetWorkItem(wiLink.TargetId)`).

If you just wanted the workitems associated to a build, then you have to iterate through its  `buildInformationNodes` looking for the Associated WorkItems node - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/tfsgeneral/thread/92766815-c09b-422b-91fc-5e745e3aaa21